# Rules replacement pattern for End Date

Tags: rules

I have a rule set up to email the contents of an entity form. I am using replacement patterns to print out the submitted data. However, I cannot get the end date to print out.

I have `[entityform:field_venue_reservation_date]` - which prints the start date fine.

Here is what the replacement pattern description states:
Field "field_venue_reservation_date". The following properties may be appended to the token: value (Start date), value2 (End date), duration (Duration)

I found a few ideas and have tried them but I still do not get the end date to print.

Here is what I tried.

```
[entityform:field_venue_reservation_date:value2]
[entityform:field_venue_reservation_date:0]
[entityform:field_venue_reservation_date:0:value:custom:Y]
```

I have been trying to search for ideas but nothing is working.
Does anyone know how this works?

Thanks!